# Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting test explorer blue exclamation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, vs-unit-testing-framework

Getting the Blue exclamation point next to a unit test and it's not actually running.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's just a matter of cleaning up the solution and rebuilding it.